# Android bitmap getPixel depends on density?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-2.3-gingerbread

Right to the code. Given

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resId);
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(resId);
```

I get

```
bitmap.getWidth() == drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() == 9
```

though the actual image is `6x6` pixels. The point is that the density is `240`, thus the scale is `1.5` to the `DENSITY_DEFAULT = 160`. That would not be such an issue itself, but `bitmap.getPixel(x, y);` does also work with the enlarged dimensions.

Settings bitmap's density seems to make no difference. How should I query the image for pixel at real position? I would rather not divide everything by the density (ofttimes not even possible).

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First a few comments on what's happening here. The Bitmap you get is actually resampled; its pixel data is for a 9x9 image. The method `bitmap.getWidth()` is not affected by calls to `bitmap.setDensity()`.

To load the Bitmap while preventing the Android framework from resampling it for you, create a [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) instance and set [inScaled](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inScaled) to `false`, then pass this to decodeResource():

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inScaled = false;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resId, options);
// Now bitmap.getWidth() == 6
```

Note that it is the resampled version that is used in the UI (unless you explicitly work around that), so if you want to do `bitmap.getPixel(x,y);` on the Bitmap that is drawn in the UI, you should not make use of `inScaled = false`.